# php how to search array keys via another array values

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have this first array

```
$rules = [ "0" => "id" , "1" => "message"];
```

And another array

```
$send = [  "id" => "132574" , "message" => "Hello!" , ... ];
```

Other parameters are not important...

I want a code to check if `$rules` values does exist in `$send` ***keys***, and if not push them into a new array like

```
$require = [id , Message];
```

***Attempt:***

```
foreach( $rules as $k => $v) {
  if ( ! array_key_exist($v , $send) { 
   ... 
  }
}
```

but it only give me the first parameter "id"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `array_keys()` and `array_diff()`

```
<?php

$send_keys = array_keys($send);

$diff_array = array_diff($rules,$send_keys);
print_r($diff_array);
```

Sample output: https://3v4l.org/4bhNp

Answer (score 1):

The solution with array_keys and array_intersect.

```
function keys_exists_in_array(array $keys, array $check){
  return $keys == array_intersect($keys, array_keys($check));
}
```

The function checks whether all values of the keys array are available as keys in the array check.

Test:

```
$rules = [ "0" => "id" , "1" => "message"];
$send = [  "id" => "132574" , "message" => "Hello!" ,"name" => "test"];
var_dump(keys_exists_in_array($rules,$send)); //true

$rules = [ "0" => "id" , "1" => "message"];
$send = [  "id" => "132574" , "name" => "test"];
var_dump(keys_exists_in_array($rules,$send)); //false
```